# HtmlTextWriter solution being added as a WebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmltextwriter

I have a solution that works, yet it doesn't meet the QA requirements from the customer. Problem is I can't control the location of the WebControls, they need to be relative to a chart that is above these. How I see it, I need to "*compile*" the sb.ToString() into a WebControl, which I'll then be able to Controls.Add().

I need to go from this working solution:

> > private void SetTextBoxes()
> >        {
> >          TextBox myBox = new TextBox();
> >          System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label myLabel =
> >                 new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
> >
> > ```
> >     // <table><tr>
> >     for (int i = 0; i < _module.Values.Count; i++)
> >     {
> >         myLabel = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
> >         myLabel.Text = _module.Values[i].Text.ToString() + ": ";
> >
> >         myBox = new TextBox();
> >         myBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
> >         myBox.ReadOnly = true;
> >         myBox.Text = _module.Values[i].Value.ToString("n0");
> >
> >         myBox.Columns = myBox.Text.Length;
> >
> >         // <td align="center">
> >         Controls.Add(myLabel);
> >         Controls.Add(myBox);
> >         // </td>
> >     }
> >     // </tr></table>
> > }
> > ```

Key is the `Controls.Add()` as it ties into a modular system covering this code and a few other WebControls.

I have a suggestion to what the solution may look like.

```
private string WriteHtml()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            htmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table);
            htmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);

            for (int i = 0; i < _module.Values.Count; i++)
            {
                htmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);

                htmlTextWriter.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1:n0}"
                    , _module.Values[i].Text
                    , _module.Values[i].Value));

                htmlTextWriter.RenderEndTag(); // td
            }
            htmlTextWriter.RenderEndTag(); // tr
            htmlTextWriter.RenderEndTag(); // table
        }
    }

    //Controls.Add(sb.ToString());
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: In what stage of life cycle you are planning to call WriteHtml() method?

Comment: SetTextBoxes() are called during the CreateChildControls(), I have assumed the WriteHtml would replace that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved almost the same task. Here is my results:

1) I created small helper method:

```
   public static void RenderControl(Control control, HtmlTextWriter response)
        {
            var sWriter = new StringWriter();
            var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);

            control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

            // Write HTML
            response.WriteLine(sWriter);
            response.Flush();
        }
```

2) At main code if you want to get rendered Html you are doing somthing like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
          Control control= new YourControlWithTextBox();
          WebControlHelper.RenderControl(control, htmlTextWriter);
          return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
    }
```

With this implementation you can leave SetTextBoxes() as is. And you get 2 version of same control. Here is 2 huge benefits: 
a)code is still readable and described in asp.net terms.
b)you can use WebControlHelper.RenderControl everywhere where you need solve simmilar task

Comment: I've had a look at your solution. It may answer somebodys answer, but I'm afraid it didn't answer this question. I read it as you end up with a list of html tags in a string mixed with some values to show. In the end I made a GridView do as I wanted and did a Controls.Add(GridView).

Comment: Even though you didn't answer my question, you still raise the consideration of the lowest common denominator(sp?). That being the string, relative to a complex object. There are functionality to convert complex web objects to a simple string, so in a way you may be more right than you realise.